# Upload Xml file to internet via FTP

Tags: java, android, xml, ftp

I'm developing a game in Android. The game has many levels and a Level Editor. So when a user make a level, the data are saving as Xml file. So I want to upload this Xml file to internet to share the other users. I searhed and tried these below codes. But It didn't work. The whole code like this:

```
                String FTP_HOST= "185.27.134.11";
                String FTP_USER = "fees0_14042425";
                String FTP_PASS  ="kadi1sd22";

                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/kadirGameLevels1/a.png");


                    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

            try {

                client.connect(FTP_HOST,21);
                client.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);
                client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
                client.changeDirectory("/levels/");

                client.upload(f, new MyTransferListener());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    client.disconnect(true);    
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

But even if I only use this single line, it still stop running. Did I something wrong with is integration or anything else?

```
       FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
```

Comment: You want users to share level data via FTP? Why FTP?

Comment: do you know better way?

Comment: I would either use a cloud service like parse (https://parse.com/) - there are many others, or write my own simple backend using something like HTTP/JSON as the transport. Using FTP seems unusual to me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the INTERNET permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This makes sure your app has the right permission to access the internet.

Also don't put any networking code in the main UI thread or you will likely get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Instead put all your FTP-connecting/accessing code into an `AsyncTask`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/833647

Comment: And the second part of my answer? Is your code in an `AsyncTask`? Are you getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`? Maybe if you post the logcat error people will be able to help better...so far I am just guessing :)